# Reconocimiento de parentesis en texto php

Tags: php7

He buscado y no encuentro sobre el tema, seguramente la respuesta es simple. Por favor ayúdenme, quiero reconocer un texto completo que incluye parentesis y no lo logro.
Este es mi código:

```
if($variable=="Monoxido de carbono (CO)"){
   echo $variable;
}
```

Cuando lo comparo con texto sin paréntisis sí funciona pero con ellos no funciona.

Comment: Sería interesante ver el resultado de un `var_dump($variable);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as una comparacion mas efectiva con:

1. el metodo `trim` elimina espacios al principio y al final del texto.
2. el metodo `strtoupper` cambia el texto a mayuscula.

`$variable = "Monoxido de carbono (CO)"; 
    if(strtoupper(trim($variable))==strtoupper(trim("Monoxido de carbono (CO)"))){
       echo $variable;
    }`

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo problema no logro entender por qué se da. Sin embargo he logrado solucionarlo con el siguiente código: if(strpos($variable, "MONOXIDO DE CARBONO (CO)"))

Comment: Saludos. A pesar de que ya había logrado conseguir el resultado deseado con strpos me quedé con la duda de porqué no reconocía la variable y encontré que la palabra me ha estado llegando con código HTML y al visualizar en el navegador las etiquetas no me aparecían porque el navegador las interpretaba. Finalmente, es por esa razón que nunca me daba igual. Eliminé las etiquetas HTML y funcionó muy bien!... gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

No debería de haber problema al compararlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

$variable="Monoxido de carbono (CO)";

if($variable=="Monoxido de carbono (CO)"){
    echo $variable;
}

?>
```

El resultado sería:

```
Monoxido de carbono (CO)
```

Puedes comprobarlo [aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff81f0944fdd597ac00543cb13d48bd82ce5a690)